# Dojo BorderContainer position its content in wrong position

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am trying to use Dojo BorderContainer, and I tried to put a BorderContainer to the html body. It seems The BorderContainer does not put things in the correct location.

Here is the code. Basically, that is the Dojo Helloword tutorial with the dojo code replaced with BorderContainer example for Dojo. (The file is a local html file hello.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

    <script>
        require([
            "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(BorderContainer, ContentPane){
            // create a BorderContainer as the top widget in the hierarchy
            var bc = new BorderContainer({
                style: "height: 300px; width: 500px;"
            });

            // create a ContentPane as the left pane in the BorderContainer
            var cp1 = new ContentPane({
                region: "left",
                style: "width: 100px",
                content: "why am i here?"
            });
            bc.addChild(cp1);

            // create a ContentPane as the center pane in the BorderContainer
            var cp2 = new ContentPane({
                region: "center",
                content: "not happy."
            });
            bc.addChild(cp2);

            // put the top level widget into the document, and then call startup()
            bc.placeAt(document.body);
            bc.startup();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is what I got:

[Browser screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckK0R.png)

Notice that the content that should have been inside the BorderContainer ("why am i here, not happy.") is higher than the "Hello" h1 tag.

I used inspect element function of Chrome. The BorderContainer is placed correctly, but the ContentPane's position attribute is set to absolute by Dojo.

```
<div class="dijitContentPane dijitBorderContainer-child dijitBorderContainer-dijitContentPane dijitBorderContainerPane dijitAlignCenter" id="dijit_layout_ContentPane_1" widgetid="dijit_layout_ContentPane_1" style="left: 100px; top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 300px;">not happy.</div>
```

The code is just copy-pasted for Dojo website, I wonder what could go wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the dojo css files (i.e., claro.css) and that's most likely why things don't look correct.